# Laravel - using cookies to display visitor specific information?

Tags: laravel

I am wondering what is considered in `Laravel 5.3` the secure and proper way to display visitor specific info in cases where the visitor is not logged in to my site.

For instance, I have a registration page where visitor can sign up for a free webinar. They enter email, choose a date, and submit. That's all. Then in my database I store info about what webinar they are registered for.

But I don't want them to always see a blank registration page. If they already registered, I would rather display a message about the webinar they registered for. I thought about forcing visitors to register on my site in order to register for a webinar, but I don't want to force visitors through multiple steps.

So I was thinking maybe this is where cookies would come in?

I read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests but the info is quite minimal.

Say someone registers for a webinar. In the form controller after successful registration there is this call:

```
return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for registering for the free webinar!');
```

The Laravel docs show cookie setting in this form:

```
return response('Hello World')->cookie(
    'name', 'value', $minutes
);
```

I figure `return->back()` is like a `response` in that I could append a cookie and tried doing this:

```
        return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for registering for the free webinar!')->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

But `cookie` is returned `null` even though `$registrant->id` is an integer.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use cookie for this. 
Laravel stores the value you returned in a session

Comment: When user closes browser then returns, wouldn't the session data be lost? I am trying to get this to work in cases where visitor returns days/weeks later.

Comment: return response()->cookie(
    'success', 'Thanks for registering for the free webinar!'
);

{{cookie('success')}}